# Invitee is in inviter tenant: Azure AD Invitations Endpoint Error

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to call the [Invitations API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0) to invite users to sign in via Microsoft Graph API.

My code works for most of the emails that I call the API on, however for some emails, I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invitee is in inviter tenant",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": <request id>,
            "date": 2019-06-03T05:51:21
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this issue occurs?

To be clear, when I first called the API on this email, the invitation email was sent successfully. However, after a few times of testing, I get this error.

I initially suspected that clicking on the 'Get Started' button in the email caused on this error and tested this hypothesis on an Outlook email. However, after clicking on the 'Get Started' button for the test email and calling the API again, the invitation email is still sent as per normal.

My code snippet is as follows:

```php
$curlStat = curl_init();
$feedURL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations';
$data_body = Array(
    'invitedUserEmailAddress' => <test-email>,
    'inviteRedirectUrl' => <my-redirect-url>,
    'sendInvitationMessage' => true
);
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . <my-access-token>,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);
$data_body = json_encode($data_body);
curl_setopt($curlStat, CURLOPT_URL, $feedURL);
curl_setopt($curlStat, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlStat, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlStat, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_body);
curl_setopt($curlStat, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$emailOutput = curl_exec($curlStat);
curl_close($curlStat);
```

Comment: Could you share your request snippet ?

Comment: You get this error when you send an invitation to somebody whose email suffix matches the verified domain names. Can you verify the email suffixes of both the invitee and inviter?

Comment: I uploaded my request snippet in the above question due to lack of space

Comment: @ManojReddy-MSFT by 'verified domain names', are you talking about the domain name for the redirect url during login?

Comment: Verified domain names in Azure AD tenant of the invitee. For example, user1@contoso.com or user1@contoso.onmicrosoft.com cannot be invited by xyz@contoso.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of two conditions that cause this (or similar) errors to fire:

1. You're attempting to invite someone with an address from one of the verified domains. In other words, if your tenant lists `company.onmicrosoft.com` and `company.com` as verified domains, attempting to invite an address ending in `@company.onmicrosoft.com` or `@company.com` will fail.
2. The external email address you supplied already exists in the tenant (typically because they've already accepted a previous invitation).

Both of these boil down to the same root cause: you cannot send an invitation to an email address that has already been assigned to an existing user.

As for why you could send an invitation immediately after accepting a prior invitation, this is likely just a race condition. It takes a few moments for the invitation to get processed, the user record created, and the changes to propagate across your AAD tenant.  Try waiting for 1 minute after accepting the invite and I suspect you'll consistently see this error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This clarifies my problem a lot!